# Regex pattern for (a and b) or (a and c) or (b and c) in mysql REGEXP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to write a regex pattern for checking if a string has (a and b) or (a and c) or (b and c) in a MySql `REGEXP`.

I wrote this but it did'nt work:

```
a&&b|a&&c|b&&c
(a,b)|(a,c)|(b,c)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: are a,b,c characters or strings?

Comment: Can you post some sample strings along with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match column string values which should contain at least two characters from sequence `(a and b) or (a and c) or (b and c)` use the following regexp:

```
'a.*b|b.*a|a.*c|c.*a|b.*c|c.*b'
```

The example(from test database):

```
SELECT id, url FROM `n_categories` 
WHERE url regexp 'a.*b|b.*a|a.*c|c.*a|b.*c|c.*b'
```

The exemplary output:

[image]

Comment: Brackets not needed.

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest very very thanks. i hope for you nice and good things.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
a.*(b|c)|b.*(a|c)|c.*(a|b)
```

The variable parts can be multiple characters. Here is some test data:

> test with aa then bb in it
>   test with bb then aa in it
>   test with aa then cc in it
>   test with cc then aa in it
>   test with bb then cc in it
>   test with cc then bb in it
>   test with only aa in it
>   test with only bb in it
>   test with only cc in it
>   test with aa, bb and cc.

You could apply this SQL to test it:

```
select txt, 
       CASE WHEN txt regexp 'aa.*(bb|cc)|bb.*(aa|cc)|cc.*(aa|bb)'
           THEN 'Yes' 
           ELSE 'No'
       END matches
from   t
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f19e3f/2), which adds a column to the test data, indicating whether there is a match or not:

```
|              txt           | matches |
|----------------------------|---------|
| test with aa then bb in it |   Yes   |
| test with bb then aa in it |   Yes   |
| test with aa then cc in it |   Yes   |
| test with cc then aa in it |   Yes   |
| test with bb then cc in it |   Yes   |
| test with cc then bb in it |   Yes   |
| test with only aa in it    |    No   |
| test with only bb in it    |    No   |
| test with only cc in it    |    No   |
| test with aa, bb and cc.   |   Yes   |
```